# How to analyze the relationship between multiple inputs and multiple outputs through big data or machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I have a lot of data, each data has 3 inputs, 6 outputs, how can I analyze the relationship between these data through big data analysis or machine learning? When the new 3 inputs are provided, the new 6 output data is automatically given.

`input:1,2,3 output:4,5,6,7,8,9
input:4,5,6 output:???`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about the capacity of a learning machine. In supervised learning, the machine learns from a lot of examples. In your case, if you have a lot of data that are labeled, you may want to build a multiple layer perceptron to study the samples. In this architecture, you would want 3 input neurons and 6 output neurons and multiple layers between them. On the other hand, if you believe there is a generating pattern in your training data, you may want to use statistical model. In either case you need a lot of data to train a machine. In your example, it would confuse a machine just like confusing a human since it has too few samples and has too much possibilities.